# What is the difference between view and view:make?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am starting to learn laravel and saw two ways to return a view.

1.

```
return View::make('login');
```

2.

```
return view('login');
```

Im not sure what the advantage of `View::make` is. Even after reading the API documentation. https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/View/Factory.html#method_make

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They both do the same, first one is through the use of Facade's
The second one is a helper method.

Doesn't matter which one you use, just choose the syntax you prefer.

Comment: Facade' s? What is this, do I need it?

Comment: Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's service container. Laravel ships with many facades which provide access to almost all of Laravel's features. Laravel facades serve as "static proxies" to underlying classes in the service container, providing the benefit of a terse, expressive syntax while maintaining more testability and flexibility than traditional static methods.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades